# Error on creating onKeyPress "Enter" ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

I'm really new to ReactJS and I haven't really gone far with my studies on React, I'm trying to set up a search box that returns the query, but for now I'm getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyCode' of undefined on

```
if(keyCode==='13')
```

What I'm trying to do is everytime I hit 'Enter' on my textbox I would get the console.log

Here's what I've tried to do

```
var searchQuery = (e) => {
    var textInput = document.getElementById('searchQuery');
        if(e.keyCode === '13'){
            console.log('Enter pressed');
        };  
    };

const SearchBar = () => {
    debugger;

  return (
    <div className="search-bar">
        <input type="text" id="searchQuery" placeholder="Enter Query" onKeyPress={searchQuery(event)}/>
    </div>
    );

};
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if(keyCode === 13){
            console.log('Enter pressed');
        };  
    };
```

and

```
onKeyPress={searchQuery}
```

Here is running code snippet of your code.

```js
var searchQuery = (e) => {
    var textInput = document.getElementById('searchQuery');
    var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if(keyCode === 13){
            console.log('Enter pressed');
        };  
    };

const SearchBar = () => {
    debugger;

  return (
    <div className="search-bar">
        <input type="text" id="searchQuery" placeholder="Enter Query" onKeyPress={searchQuery}/>
    </div>
    );

};

ReactDOM.render(
  <SearchBar/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, may you explain how come my work didn't work? And why yours did? It would be very helpful.

Comment: The keypress returns character value, and the keycode will be 0 in that case. The `which` property returns the Unicode character code of the key that triggered the onkeypress event. You can read more at w3 documentation https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keypress and the mozilla documentation for `which` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which

Answer (score 0):

i don't know react very well, but it should be just like

```
onKeyPress={searchQuery}
```

Type 'function name', without arguments.

Comment: thanks that was correct, however when it goes to my if statement when I used debugger, it doesn't detect the keycode of 'Enter', care to shed some light? Thank you

Comment: the reason is because onKeyPress will execute for any key that is pressed.